# usb hard drive/pen drive emulation via bios

Tags: dos, bios, usb-drive, usb-flash-drive

I am trying to read/write usb hard drives and flash drives for a DOS application.

I read [EDD spec.](http://www.t10.org/t13/technical/d98120r0.pdf) and it mentions that function Int13(Fn = 48h) can be used to get *interface path* and *device path*  for a particular disk drive. This also includes usb interface and ata interface.

Now this function also returns a *Device Parameter Table Extension (DPTE)*  table that gives I/O addresses via which a software bypassing Int13h can use to read/write the device. But this table is *only* for ATA afaik.

I wanna read/write to usb disk/pen drives *w/o using Int 13h.* Is it possible?

Actually it is a disk I/O sensitive application in protected mode. So using Int13h would involve heavy penalty in terms of performance, due to mode switching. So, I am trying to avoid using Int13h.

Does bios initalizes usb drives to appear as ATA drives too. If so, then I can use DPTE to get the I/O base addresses of the command block and control block and then access the usb drives just like ATA drives. Am I right?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This particular issue has been discussed at length among the FreeDOS community. The best guide to the whole issue is the FreeDOS technote "[USB with DOS](http://www.freedos.org/technotes/newsitem/149.html)"